# calling Magento services return error "Unrecognized message version."

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, magento

I'm trying to call Magento web service using WCF. but i kept getting the following error message. the web service can be views in chrome without any difficulty.

app.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999" />


            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://xxx.co.uk/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding"
                contract="PoqService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType"
                name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>




System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unrecognized message version.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at pedlars.testing.PoqService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortType.login(String username, String apiKey)
       at pedlars.testing.PoqService.Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient.login(String username, String apiKey) in c:\Users\j\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\pedlars.testing\pedlars.testing\Service References\PoqService\Reference.cs:line 28802
       at pedlars.testing.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\j\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\pedlars.testing\pedlars.testing\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: try the same message with SoapUI, I'm always starting with SoapUI new integration. Also I've worked with magento API V2 before from C# and it worked fine, so may be show your client configuration, maybe you're using different SOAP version.

Comment: thanks for that. it returns me error on loading WSDL ' could not find type 'anyType@urn:Magento'. Do you mean to refer to the element named anyType@http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/(in soapEncoding.xsd)?'

Comment: I can't see anyType in my wsdl, I've used link http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl, also I think endpoint should not point to wsdl in url, if you've imported wsdl into SoapUI, it should resolve right endpoint addresses, mine was http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/

Comment: thanks Giedrius, that tiny small mistake about using a link with the wsdl drove me nuts...